# Python find frequency of numbers in list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a `list` of lists of `int` as shown below

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [1, 5],
 [4, 2, 6]]
```

I want to generate the frequency of the numbers in the lists as a `dict`, for example `1` occurs in `2` of the lists, and so on, expected output is

```
{1:2,
 2:2,
 3:1,
 4:1,
 5:1,
 6:1}
```

How can this be generated?

Comment: What's the expected output when the input list is `[[1, 1, 2], [2, 2]]`? Is it going to be `{1: 1, 2: 2}`, or is it `{1: 2, 2: 3}`?

Comment: In that case output should be `{1: 2, 2: 3}`

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

L is your list of list.
expected = {1:2,
2:2,
3:1,
4:1,
5:1,
6:1}

```py
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> flattened = list(chain.from_iterable(L))
>>> flattened
[1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 2, 6]
>>> counts = Counter(flattened)
>>> counts
Counter({1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 5: 1, 4: 1, 6: 1})

# It's easy to make it to a function or one-liner too.
>>> counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(L))

>>> assert counts == expected     # your expected result shown above
#   silence means matching.
```

Comment: The description that "`1` occurs in `2` of the lists" makes it sound like it shouldn't count duplicates within a list.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean.  It's exactly matching the OP's expected result.

Comment: OP's example doesn't happen to contain any sublists with duplicate elements, but if that is possible then this would be different than the number of lists which an element occurs in.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Counter` for this

```
>>> from collections import Counter as c
>>> array = [[1, 2, 3],[1,5],[4,2,6]]
>>> result = c()
>>> for sublist in array:
...     result += c(sublist)
... 
>>> result
Counter({1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 5: 1, 4: 1, 6: 1})
```